# How to prevent ini folder from being deleted (InstallShield 2011)

Tags: installation, installshield, uninstallation, ini, setup.exe

I'm trying to prevent my ini folder from a previous version of my installation from being deleted from the uninstall of the New installation.

I'm using InstallShield 2011, and am wondering how (if at all possible) to execute an setup.exe that will copy/ move (or just move) the ini folder so that the newest version cant uninstall it and so we can grab it at a later time for use in the new installation. I need the setup.exe to execute before the uninstall (obviously to retrive the folder), on past attempts of xcopy the uninstall still found its way to the folder and removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom action (on InstallScript or VBScript, for example) and launch it before **RemoveExistingProducts** action. Custom action will backup these ini files to somewhere. Then second custom action will restore them.
For future set *permanent* attribute for ini component to prevent removing during uninstallation.